# How to change text color to white for form input labels and paragraphs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hie, I have a signup form on top of a full-screen video. I am using Bootstrap and I don't know how to get white text color for my form labels and the paragraph beside the form. I am still very new to Bootstrap I have so far only found  colors, the paragraph class colors conflict with my design, I just need to get white but I don't know how to do it.
I realize that this may be all to simple and I apologize and I apologize in advance if that is the case. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<section class="container">
    <div class="container-page">                
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="dark-grey">Registration</h3>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label>Repeat Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label>Email Address</label>
                <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                <label>Repeat Email Address</label>
                <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
            </div>          

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />Sigh up for our newsletter
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />Send notifications to this email
            </div>              

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="dark-grey">Terms and Conditions</h3>
            <p>
                By clicking on "Register" you agree to The Company's' Terms and Conditions
            </p>
            <p>
                While rare, prices are subject to change based on exchange rate fluctuations - 
                should such a fluctuation happen, we may request an additional payment. You have the option to request a full refund or to pay the new price. (Paragraph 13.5.8)
            </p>
            <p>
                Should there be an error in the description or pricing of a product, we will provide you with a full refund (Paragraph 13.5.6)
            </p>
            <p>
                Acceptance of an order by us is dependent on our suppliers ability to provide the product. (Paragraph 13.5.6)
            </p>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
form, input, label, p {
    color: white !important;
}
```

In most cases when using bootstrap, you will need `!important` to override the existing bootstrap css style.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply white color to label and p tag as below

```
.form-group label, p{
  color: #fff;
}
```

it it doesnt work use `!important`

```
.form-group label, p{
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}
p,label {
  color: white;
}
```

See codepen here: http://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/NbjOgJ